# log4j2 root level not working

Tags: spring-mvc, log4j2

I am new to log4j2, now I have got log4j2 initialized and working yet I can not set the root logger level.

My project is a Java Web Project( I am using MyEclipse on windows7 x64), and I run it in Tomcat 7.0.52.

I use this in a class :

```
    log.trace("Here is some TRACE");
    log.debug("Here is some DEBUG");
    log.info("Here is some INFO");
    log.warn("Here is some WARN");
    log.error("Here is some ERROR");
    log.fatal("Here is some FATAL");
```

only got the error and fatal message, which according to the document, I think is the default setting of log4j2. That means my own configuration is of no effect.

My log4j2.xml as :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<configuration status="OFF">  
  <appenders>  
    <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">  
      <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>  
    </Console>
    <File name="File" fileName="logs/example.log">
         <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
    </File>  
  </appenders>  
  <loggers>  

    <root level="debug">  
      <appender-ref ref="Console"/>  
      <appender-ref ref="File"/>  
    </root>  
  </loggers>  
</configuration>
```

My `log4j2.xml` file have been placed under a package and I configure web.xml as this:

```
  <context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>classpath:/path/to/a/package/log4j2.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>

   <context-param>
    <param-name>log4jRefreshInterval</param-name>
    <param-value>60000</param-value>
   </context-param>

 <listener>
  <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
 </listener>
```

According to the deploy log, I think log4j2 did find the configuration file:

```
INFO: Initializing log4j from [classpath:/path/to/a/package/log4j2.xml]
INFO 24, 2014 3:37:34  org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Log4jServletContextListener ensuring that Log4j starts up properly.
INFO 24, 2014 3:37:34  org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Log4jServletFilter initialized.
```

Can you help finding out what's the problem?

Thanks to @Remko for mentioning `log4j.configurationFile` and I google a bit to find out what's `system property`.

Previously, I did read about automation configuration session in log4j2's [documentation](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html) , but I don't quite understand the `system property` so I just ignored it.

I still not sure about relationship between `<context-param>` and `system property`, so I tried this:

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>log4j.configurationFile</param-name>
  <param-value>classpath:/path/to/a/package/log4j2.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

that doesn't work.

Secondly I tried adding `-Dlog4j.configurationFile="CLASSPATH:/path/to/a/package/log4j2.xml"` to tomcat's startup option, This should work, but still it didn't.

I find that my problem it the same as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14733698/log4j-2-configuration-issue)

Maybe the configurationFile doesn't support `CLASSPATH` notation, so I try to use a absolute path 
`-Dlog4j.configurationFile="F:\MySpace\myproject\src\foo\blabla\resource\log4j2.xml"`

Still, it's not working..

Comment: The `classpath:path` notation is supported for location, but must be *lowercase*.

Comment: Tip: You can check that Log4J2 found the log4j2.xml configuration file by changing your configuration to start with `<configuration status="trace">`. This will print log4j2 internal logging to the console (the Tomcat console in your example) once log4j2 finds the log4j2.xml file.

Comment: Tip2: Enable the internal log4j status logger by setting system property `-Dlog4j2.StatusLogger.level=TRACE`. This should print details of log4j2 initialization to the console. It may give a hint for where things are going wrong...

Answer (score 0):

Try putting log4j2.xml under WEB-INF/classes/ in your war file. No need to configure location in web.xml in that case.

---

UPDATE:
The property name specified in the web.xml (`log4jConfigLocation`) is *for Log4J-1.2, not for Log4J2*.

The correct property name for Log4J2 is `log4j.configurationFile`. (In spite of its name it accepts not just files but also understands the `classpath:` scheme.)

Comment: I know if I just place the `log4j2.xml` in `WEB-INF/classes/` or in `src` it will be fine. But What am curious is that the log show it did read the configuration from place I configure, yet it is of no effect.

Comment: Hmm... It should probably say it is *trying* to initialize from `classpath:/path/to/a/package/log4j2.xml`. It should report a clear error if it could not find anything at that location. By the way, I have had similar issues in the past: what if you remove the initial slash and use `classpath:path/to/a/package/log4j2.xml` instead?

Comment: I don't think it has something to do with initial slash, I have other entry with this initial slash, they work fine. Though I try you advice by removing initial slash, it doesn't work.