# None of my log4j configuration changes have any effect on output. (In IntelliJ)

Tags: java, intellij-idea, log4j2

I'm trying to setup a "hello world" style class to spit hello out to some logs, using IntelliJ IDEA Community 2016.1, JDK 1.8, and log4j 2.5. I've tried both *.properties* files and programmatic configuration; neither have had any impact at all on the output.

**My properties files don't work.**

Just about every problem of this nature I've seen on Stackoverflow suggests that the properties file needs to be on the classpath. To be clear, **my config seems to be on the classpath, as I'm no longer getting the log4j error message that it can't find the properties file.** I've also tried specifying it with

```
-Dlog4j.configurationFile=[FULLY SPECIFIED PATH]
```

and seen no change in the output.

**Programmatic configuration also doesn't work.**

I've tried using the Basic Configurator (ripped right from the sample again) and I still see no change in output.

To be clear: whether the properties file is found or not, the output is *identical*, except that the "No log4j2 configuration File found" message appears or doesn't in a sensible way.

Here's my code:

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;

public class HelloWorld {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(HelloWorld.class);

    logger.info("Hello World of logging!");
    logger.info("Working Dir: " + System.getProperty("user.dir"));

    logger.debug("debug test");
    logger.info("info test");
    logger.warn("warn test");
    logger.error("error test");

    if (!logger.isDebugEnabled())
        logger.error("Debug isn't enabled. :(");

    if (!logger.isInfoEnabled())
        logger.error("Info isn't enabled. :(");

    if (!logger.isWarnEnabled())
        logger.error("Warn isn't enabled. :(");

}
```

And here is its full output in the console:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_77\bin\java" ...
09:51:10.142 [main] ERROR HelloWorld - error test
09:51:10.142 [main] ERROR HelloWorld - Debug isn't enabled. :(
09:51:10.142 [main] ERROR HelloWorld - Info isn't enabled. :(
09:51:10.143 [main] ERROR HelloWorld - Warn isn't enabled. :(

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I've tried many different config files (all of the *.properties* non-xml variety) from [the manual](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html) to no avail: no change in output format. Here's the one I keep falling back on as it's the first example they use. Even though the level's set at DEBUG I only see ERROR level messages, and the format doesn't match the ConversionPattern at all.

```
# Set root logger level to DEBUG and its only appender to A1.
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, A1

# A1 is set to be a ConsoleAppender.
log4j.appender.A1=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender

# A1 uses PatternLayout.
log4j.appender.A1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.A1.layout.ConversionPattern=%-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n
```

Both of the log4j2 jars are under my *External Libraries* section within my project: *log4j-api-2.5jar* and *log4j-core-2.5.jar*; the code compiles and runs.

I'm at a complete loss here but still banging my hands on it. If any of you have any ideas or have seen this before, I'd really appreciate your thoughts. Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Have you tried a simple xml-config?

Comment: Seems similar issue is discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14733698/log4j-2-configuration-issue?rq=1)

Comment: Erm, you linked to the log4j 1.2 Manual. I guess you should stick to log4j 2 manual: http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html

Comment: oh no, I was in the wrong manual. >_< uuuuug. Well, a dumb mistake's better than something egregiously wrong with my env. I'll have a look see if the solution's in there, ty.

Also, I haven't tried XML yet, so I could give that a shot.

Comment: Also you could try enable log4j debugging info by setting `-Dlog4j.debug=true`

Answer (score 0):

Per Fildor's comment above, my issue was that I was in fact looking in the wrong manual. :\ My link above is to v1.2, while I was using log4j v2.5.

There are very significant differences between the two versions insofar as how they're configured.

This config xml works:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="debug">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Producing this output:

```
10:53:25.385 [main] INFO  HelloWorld - Hello World of logging!
10:53:25.385 [main] INFO  HelloWorld - Working Dir: C:\Users\thade\IdeaProjects\HelloWorldOfLogging
10:53:25.386 [main] DEBUG HelloWorld - debug test
10:53:25.386 [main] INFO  HelloWorld - info test
10:53:25.386 [main] WARN  HelloWorld - warn test
10:53:25.386 [main] ERROR HelloWorld - error test
```

Here's [the manual you want](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html) if you run into this. If I were to guess how I got here, it's because I initially started with *slf4j* which works against the log4j 1.2 *API* and while there are API bridges, dropping into the 1.2 manual was a mistake.

Thanks everybody for bagging this so quickly.