# Log4j2 Amazon ec2 file logging not working

Tags: java, log4j2, rollingfileappender

I just converted my java server to use Log4j2 from 1.

My file logs worked just fine with Log4j1:

```
try {
    Date currentStamp = new Date();
    String sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd_HH.mm.ss").format(currentStamp);
    File theFile = new File("logs/");
    theFile.mkdirs();

    fileAppender = new RollingFileAppender(
            new PatternLayout("[%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}] %r [%t] %p %C - %m%n"),
            "logs/" + sdf + "_serverLog.txt");
    fileAppender.setMaxFileSize("50MB");
    fileAppender.setMaxBackupIndex(50); //2.5 gigs
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Here is my new configuration with Log4j2 (which works fine on my local pc - console/file/email logging works no problem):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration xmlns="http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/config">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="STDOUT" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%-5p | %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} | [%t] %C{2} (%F:%L) - %m%n" />
        </Console>

        <RollingRandomAccessFile name="FILE" fileName="logs/serverLog.txt" filePattern="logs/serverLog_%d{yyyy-MM-dd}_%i.txt">
            <PatternLayout>
                <Pattern>%-5p | %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} | [%t] %C{2} (%F:%L) - %m%n</Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="50 MB"/>
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="50"/>
        </RollingRandomAccessFile>

        <SMTP name="EMAIL"
            subject="REMOVED"
            from="REMOVED"
            to="REMOVED"
            smtpHost="REMOVED"
            smtpPort="REMOVED"
            smtpUsername="REMOVED"
            smtpPassword="REMOVED"
            bufferSize="REMOVED">
        </SMTP>
    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="com.jayavon.game" level="debug" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT" />
            <AppenderRef ref="FILE" />
        </Logger>
        <Root level="error" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="EMAIL" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

My PROD (ec2) server is called via:

```
nohup /home/ec2-user/bin/startJayServer.sh &
```

And this script is:

```
#!/bin/sh

cd /home/ec2-user/JayServer
CLASSPATH="/home/ec2-user/JayServer/bin:/home/ec2-user/JayServer/lib/*" java -server com.jayavon.game.server.MyServer -PROD > /dev/null 2>logs/server.err
```

The server startup script and the nohup command were working fine with Log4j1 (i.e. folder permissions are fine).  On DEV (my windows 10 machine), the console output works in eclipse and files are created (error emails work too).  My PROD server starts fine, but no file log is created in my "**/home/ec2-user/JayServer/logs**" folder.  Any ideas?

Comment: *"Any ideas?"* - Are the pathnames correct for the prod environment? Are the directory permissions correct?  Are you using apparmor or se-linux or some other MAC framework that would stop your web container writing into a user directory ... irrespective of the normal permissions?

Comment: Are you using log4j1/2 directly or via a facade; e.g. slf4j.

Comment: Found my solution on another post  "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14733698/log4j-2-configuration-issue" - "I put my log4j2.xml under src/ directory. It works."

Answer (score 0):

Found my solution on another post "[log4j 2 - configuration issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14733698/log4j-2-configuration-issue)"

"I put my log4j2.xml under src/ directory. It works."

Thanks @fstang