# Log4j2 error on load XML configuration file

Tags: java, xml, configuration, load, log4j2

I'm trying to use an XML configuration file for Log4j2 that is embedded in my Java application, but is not working.

The code:

```
ConfigurationSource source = new ConfigurationSource(Main.class.getResourceAsStream("/in/gunbound/prelauncher/server/log4j2/log4j2.xml"));
ConfigurationFactory factory = (ConfigurationFactory) XMLConfigurationFactory.getInstance().getConfiguration(source);
ConfigurationFactory.setConfigurationFactory(factory);
```

The error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.XMLConfiguration cannot be cast
>   to org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationFactory  at
>   in.gunbound.prelauncher.server.Main.main(Main.java:62)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use the `ConfigurationFactory` when you use a XML-Configuration file. Just make sure your XML file is setup correctly.

Filename must be `log4j2.xml`

The file must me added to the classPath.

Get the logger with the right name in your applicaton, the same name you used to set up the logger in your xml-file, have a [look here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13235751/1515052).

Comment: Adding a file to classpath is not always "easy", e.g. if you create a desktop application with javapackager, you get e.g. an .exe file which starts the application. For "normal" java programs that are started with 'java -jar' it is easier (also in those cases the logger configuration usually is in a folder next to the jar, in which case the jar manifest can describe the classpath. But if the javapackager created installer installs to program files, you could not edit that log4j conf file unless you are admin)

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problem. Here is example that helped me: https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/logging/log4j/log4j2/trunk/core/src/test/java/org/apache/logging/log4j/FormatterLoggerManualExample.java

In your case it should look like this:

```
URI configuration = Main.class.getResource("/in/gunbound/prelauncher/server/log4j2/log4j2.xml").toURI();
Configurator.initialize("config", null, configuration);
```

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem, solved it like this:

```
import java.io.InputStream;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Configuration;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationFactory.ConfigurationSource;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.XMLConfigurationFactory;

public class Log
{

    private Logger logger;

    public Log(String name)
    {
        InputStream is = Application.class.getResourceAsStream("log-config.xml");
        ConfigurationSource source = new ConfigurationSource(is);
        Configuration config = XMLConfigurationFactory.getInstance().getConfiguration(source);
        LoggerContext ctx = (LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(true);

        ctx.stop();
        ctx.start(config);

        logger = ctx.getLogger(name);
    }

    public Logger getLog()
    {
        return logger;
    }

}
```

I'm currently using log4j2 beta 9 with a databaseAppender for writing into a ora db.

Answer (score 2):

Shortest way (without creation of factory, source or url objects):

```
Configurator.initialize("configName", "logging.xml");
```

This works even if the configuration file is not named "log4j2.*".