# Unable to define custom Log4j2 configuration file in pom.xml

Tags: xml, maven, pom.xml, log4j2

I've been struggling with this a lot. 
I have a `log4j2.xml` file in my resources folder of a maven project. Everything works fine as long as I don't change the name of this configuration file. I want the configuration name to be `dev-log4j2.xml`.

I'm aware that by default, log4j looks for log4j2.xml, however, upon a lot of search I came across a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30132945/4159199) which suggests to add the following lines to define a custom path to the configuration.

```
<systemProperties>
    <property>
       <name>log4j.configuration</name>
       <value>src/main/resources/dev-log4j2.xml</value>
    </property>
</systemProperties>
```

but even this doesn't log anything in my log file. Can anyone direct me in a proper direction?

Comment: Do you need the above configuration for your tests? Apart from that the file will be automatically being copied to `target/classes` so the the folder `src/main/resources` is simply wrong and should be omitted.

Comment: No, I need it for general logging of the events. Not specifically for tests.

Comment: So, you mean `<value>dev-log4j2.xml</value>` should work?

Comment: I assume so, cause if you put the `dev-log4j2.xml` into `src/main/resources` it will end up int `target/classes`.....

Comment: Doesn't work, `"no configuration file found "`

Comment: Isn't the system/user property `log4j.configurationFile` as opposed to `log4j.configuration`?